# failed to create nx workspace due to applocker constraints on windows

Tags: angular, windows, npm, npx, nrwl-nx

I am checking nx for our Angular enterprise environment. For this I executed "npx create-nx-workspace@latest ".

Later in the installation process it fails due to applocker constraints.

Applocker blocks the execution of the script C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-3784-XIMdt41a5XET\node_modules.bin\tao.cmd because the path is random and the script not signed.

Question: Is there a way to configure the execution path of these intermediate installation scripts to a directory that has special applocker approval to execute unsigned scripts ? Or is there a way to change the execution directory to a path, that can be configured via npm config like "npm-cache" ?